# Завершение приложения в Objective-C

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Подобной темы не находила, гуглила не нашла...
Каким кодом можно завершить приложение?

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться зачем это делать в iOS?

Answer (score 6):

В операционной системе iOS не принято завершать приложения „изнутри“ — это должен делать пользователь (либо система, если ей это будет необходимо).

[Technical Q&A QA1561 — How do I programmatically quit my iOS application?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

`[[NSThread mainThread] exit]`

`[[NSApplication terminate:]]`

[documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Ну и сишный exit(int) никуда не делся, я даже где-то так делал помнится, правда это был внутренний проект одной конторы, хотя @VioLet верно заметил что в общем и целом так делать не принято

Answer (score 0):

Если хочешь по нажатию кнопки,то

```
 - (IBaction)ButtonName:(id)sender{
    exit(0);}
```